# addError is not working and allowed to store more than 3 child for corresponding parent

Tags: trigger, adderror

Requirement : not allowed to save more than 3 child for a parent
here is trigger code

```java
trigger counterCh on Contact(before insert,before update){

    if(Trigger.isInsert || Trigger.isUpdate){
        set<ID> AccountIds = new set<ID>();
        for(Contact con : Trigger.New){
            AccountIds.add(con.AccountId);
        }
        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
        accList = [Select id, (Select id from Contacts) from Account where ID IN : AccountIds];

        Contact con = new Contact();

        Integer c;

        for(Account acc : accList){
            c = acc.contacts.size();
        }
        System.debug('Count Record -->'+c);

        if(c > 3){
            con.addError('not allowed more then 3 child');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `addError()` on an sObject that is not part of the trigger's operation (the set of objects in `Trigger.new`, in this case) has no effect:

```
Contact con = new Contact();
con.addError('not allowed more then 3 child');
```

If you do not want the trigger's operation to complete successfully, you need to call `addError()` on one or more of the contacts in `Trigger.new`. Be aware that this may result in the entire set of Contacts failing to save, depending on whether the operation that inserted them used `allOrNone = false`.

Additionally, the logic in this trigger is very confused. You're comparing `c > 5`, but showing an error message about 3 children. Iterating over your `Accounts` like this:

```
for(Account acc : accList){
    c = acc.contacts.size();
}
```

Just gives you the count of the Contacts on whatever Account happens to be last in the list. You would then fail *all* of your Contacts, regardless of which Account they are associated with.

If you want to implement this right, you need to loop over `Trigger.new` *again* and add an error to each Contact if its *corresponding* Account has more than 3 contacts. Typically, `accList` would need to be a `Map<Id, Account>` so that you can do

```
for (Contact con : Trigger.new) {
    if (accMap.get(con.AccountId).Contacts.size() > 3) {
        // add an error to this Contact.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the before insert case, the contacts are not yet committed, and so won't appear in a query, so you need to use *after insert* instead. Likewise for *before update*; if the account has changed, this won't be reflected in the database yet.

```
trigger preventMoreThan3 on Contact (after insert, after update, after undelete) {
  Set<Id> accountIds = new Set<Id>();
  for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    accountIds.add(record.AccountId);
  }
  accountIds.remove(null);
  Map<Id, AggregateResult> counters = new Map<id, AggregateResult>([
    SELECT COUNT(Id) sum, AccountId Id FROM Contact
    WHERE AccountId = :accountIds
    GROUP BY AccountId]);
  for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
    if(counters.containsKey(record.AccountId) && 
        (Decimal)counters.get(record.AccountId).get('sum') > 3) {
      record.AccountId.addError('Each account may have no more than three contacts.');
    }
  }
}
```